# dictionary of dictionary in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
tags = {'stream', 'auth'} 
tags['stream']= {}
tags["stream"]["path"]= ["/streams"]
tags['stream']['attribute']= ['id', 'secure', 'cpcode', 'format', 'event_pattern']
```

The above code throws an error:

```
    tags["stream"]= {} 
TypeError: 'set' object does not support item assignment
```

How to create a dictionary of dictionary of list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`{'stream', 'auth'}` is a set literal, not a dictionary.

Use a dictionary literal:

```
tags = {'stream': {}, 'auth': {}}
tags["stream"]["path"]= ["/streams"]
tags['stream']['attribute']= ['id', 'secure', 'cpcode', 'format', 'event_pattern']
```

---

```
>>> type({'stream', 'auth'})
<type 'set'>
>>> type({'stream': {}, 'auth': {}})
<type 'dict'>
>>>
```

Answer (score 5):

You created a `set`, not a dictionary. You need to specify key-value pairs:

```
tags = {'stream': None, 'auth': None}
```

or specify the nested dictionary in literal notation in-place:

```
tags = {
    'stream': {
        'path': ["/streams"],
        'attribute': ['id', 'secure', 'cpcode', 'format', 'event_pattern'],
    }, 
    'auth': None,
}
```

The `{value, value, value}` syntax (no keys) is the set literal notation.